# オブジェクトを生成する際、クラスの後の()を省略できたと思うのですが…

Tags: php

**インスタンス生成は、「new A()」だけではなく「new A」でも可ということを、ドキュメントで確認したいのですが…**
・どこかに記載されているでしょうか？
・()は必須？

http://php.net/manual/ja/language.oop5.basic.php

---

```
class A
{
}

new A();

new A;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

※PHPは使用したことがないので見当はずれな回答でしたら済みません

`new`に関する言語仕様は下記のリンクかと思います。

Specification for PHP - The new Operator
https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/a610388d637b67294925d3b1dbbc0a54b7d94428/spec/php-spec-draft.md#the-new-operator

**Syntax**

```
  object-creation-expression:
    new  class-type-designator  (  argument-expression-listopt  )
    new  class-type-designator
```

**Semantics**

> The object is initialized by calling the class's constructor (§§) passing it the optional argument-expression-list. If the class has no constructor, the constructor that class inherits (if any) is used. Otherwise, each instance property takes on the value NULL.

コンストラクタの`argument-expression-list`はOptionalなので省略可能で、`()`も省略可能です。

引数(括弧)なしのコンストラクタでインスタンス化すると、各インスタンスプロパティは`NULL`で初期化されます。
(引数なしのコンストラクタ内で明示的に初期化されない限り)

言語仕様に例として書かれている`Point`クラスではデフォルト値に`0`が指定されているため、コンストラクタの引数(括弧)を省略した場合、`$x`と`$y`が`0`で初期化されます。

```
class Point 
{
  public function __construct($x = 0, $y = 0) 
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
$p1 = new Point;     // create Point(0, 0)
$p1 = new Point(12);   // create Point(12, 0)
```

---

> ちなみにですが、このページはどういう位置付けに該当するページなのでしょうか？

git.php.net: Git Repository ¶
https://www.php.net/sites.php#git

> The Git repository is also mirrored on GitHub, for those who would prefer to use GitHub's interface.

https://github.com/php は http://git.php.net/ のGitリポジトリをGitHub上にミラーしてるOrganizationです。

php-langspecは、PHP言語仕様 を 実装仕様(実装依存) から明確に分離することを目的に作られたドキュメントのようです。(PHP言語界隈に明るくないため詳細は不明です)

**参考リンク**

PHPの今とこれから2014
http://www.slideshare.net/hirokawa/php2014-40144066/23

Comment: 質問は `argument-expression-list` がOptinalということが問題ではないので、Syntaxとして()ありと()なしの両パターンとも `object-creation-expression` になるとするといいかと思います。しかし、本家SOでも誰も見つけらてなかった公式のドキュメントを見つけられたのは凄いですね。+1

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。回答に反映しました。

Comment: こんな所に掲載されていたのですね(このページを初めて見ました)。ちなみにですが、このページはどういう位置付けに該当するページなのでしょうか？ これまで公式マニュアル「http://php.net/manual/en/」を公式ドキュメントと思っていたのですが…。githubなのでこちらはコミュニティの開発ページ？ ここで開発された内容を整理したものを公式マニュアルとして掲載という感じなのでしょうか？

Comment: @re9 php-langspecの位置づけについて回答を追記しました。ご確認ください。

Comment: 「PHPは使用したことがない」と書いているのに無茶振りして申し訳ありません。どこに情報が掲載されているのか疑問に思いコメント追記したのですが、最終的には英語ページに行き着くわけですね。検索していくのに英語力は必要だと改めて感じました。大変参考になりました！

Answer (score 1):

私はこの省略記法を知らなかったので調べてみましたが、公式ドキュメントには「省略できる」との記述は見当たりませんでしたね…。
ただし公式ドキュメント内のExampleコードにおいては省略した記法が多用されているため、そのようなことはできるようです。
(実は`()`をつける場合ついても明確な記載は見つけられなかったのですが…)

`php new without brackets`とGoogleで検索すると本家Stack Overflowの質問がいくつもヒットし、その中では`()`つきの場合と全く同じとみなして構わないといった回答がついているようです。

明確さのない良くない回答ですが、もし参考になれば。